# Why no floating output?

Tags: python, powershell, floating-point-conversion

Just started to learn Python. Why when I run this program in PowerShell the outcome is without floating numbers on line 9 and 10?

```py
height = 74.0 #inches
weight = 180.0 #lbs

#converts from inches to cm/ and from lbs to kg.
cm = height * 2.5400    
kg = weight * 0.453592

print ""
print "Height %d inches in cm is %d " % (height, cm)    
print "Weight in %d lbs in kg is %d " % (weight, kg)

print type(kg)
print type(cm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `%d`, which is for printing integers. It's converting the floats to integers.

I would recommend using the `format` method instead of `%`:

```
print 'Height {} inches in cm is {}'.format(height, cm)
```

though it's simple enough to do it right with `%`:

```
print "Height %s inches in cm is %s" % (height, cm)
```

`%s` calls `str` on the arguments.

Comment: In case floating point numbers should be presented with a fixed number of decimals, `{:.3f}` (or `%.3f` respectively) would be another option.